# How to fix navbar-brand not to go down when toggle the button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

It goes well in desktop but I have a problem when in responsive mode

```html
<header class="header">
        <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm bg-warning">
            <div class="container">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                    aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" href="#about">About</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Project</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Took me for two days and I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: What do you mean "go down"? Nothing happening when you click on the button within the snippet.

Comment: I mean the <a> tag won't fix when I hit the toggle button in responsive mode

Comment: So i found out that `<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm bg-warning">` the navbar class has the code `flex-wrap: wrap;` and this is causing the problem. So far still looking for a solution

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works?

I added 2 classes

From container 1 i changed the width so the other div can fit next to the other div.

With the center-top i added that the div with My project text doesn't get the value from navbar and this makes him to center at the top.

```css
.container1
{
      width: 75%;
    padding-right: var(--bs-gutter-x,.75rem);
    padding-left: var(--bs-gutter-x,.75rem);
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.center-top
{
  align-items: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header class="header">
        <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm bg-warning">
            <div class="container1">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                    aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" href="#about">About</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
                        <div>
                <a class="navbar-brand center-top" href="#">My Project</a>
              </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: Yes, but I mean the <a> that has a class name ''navbar-brand'' that will drop down when I hit the toggle button in responsive mode

Comment: I have changed my answer hope this is the solution you are looking for

Comment: @Blacxloaf Did this answer work for you? if so please accept the answer so i know it works